# Below code does not check for the existing username

Tags: python, cs50

I am trying to register a user. I am having problem in preventing the user to register if the username typed already exists in the database.

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")

    elif request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 400)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 400)

        # Ensure password confirmation was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password-confirmation"):
            return apology("must provide password confirmation", 400)

        # Check if the password confirmation field matches the password field
        elif request.form.get("password-confirmation") != request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("Your passwords didn't match", 400)

        # Query database for that username
        row = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Database
        database = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

        # Ensure username is not already in the database
        if row in database:
            return apology("username already exists", 400)

        # Insert username and password into the database AND Hash user's password
        insert = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username,hash) VALUES(?,?)" , request.form.get("username"), generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = insert

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")
```

**Instead of getting "username already exists",  I get "internal server error".**

Can someone please specify why it might be the case.?

Comment: `db.execute` likely requires an iterable containing the username to search for, not just the username itself, as an argument. `row = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", (request.form.get("username"),))`

Comment: Can you please elaborate  a bit.?

Comment: Hello @chepner, Can you please elaborate a bit on your above comment.? 
Awaiting your kind response

Comment: Read the documentation for whatever database library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` syntax is wrong. It should be `rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=request.form.get("username"))`

Comment: Are ":username" and "?" not the same things.? Both are placeholders, right.?

Answer (score 0):

This `if row in database:` will never be true.

`row` is a list, so it is trying to find a *list* in `database`. `database` is itself a list, but does not contain any lists, only dictionaries.

Program would know if username is already in users if `row` is not the empty list. Hint, Hint.